# Groovy download image from URL

Tags: image, url, groovy, download

I am wondering what the proper way to go about downloading the image from this RUL would be: http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/img/port/7018246/1

The way I tried downloading it, leaves the file in an unknown format. Current code snippet I tested out is:

```
public void download(def address) {

    def file = new FileOutputStream(address.tokenize("/")[-1])
    def out = new BufferedOutputStream(file)
    out << new URL(address).openStream()
    out.close()
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does this work? I believe it should:

```
public void download(def address) {
  new File("${address.tokenize('/')[-1]}.png").withOutputStream { out ->
    out << new URL(address).openStream()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Thanks Tim, I also found your answer very helpful, just small note: 
Looks like you haven't closed URL stream. I'm just starting with Groovy, and I've heard that it close steams when exit from closure so we can change code like that:

```
public void download(def address) {
  new File("${address.tokenize('/')[-1]}.png").withOutputStream { out ->
      new URL(address).withInputStream { from ->  out << from; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get image type from their content type - [URLConnection.getContentType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType--) or from byte array:

```
content="http://www.google.ru/images/logo.png".toURL().getBytes()
ext=URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)).replaceFirst("^image/","")
new File("logo."+ext).setBytes(content)
```