# How to download a JAR file from a URL using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a JAR artifact in my nexus repository and I want to download it using Groovy script.

I tired this but it doesn't work:

```
new File("/dir/to/save/app.jar").withOutputStream { out ->
    new URL('http://server.org.com/nexus/repo/1.11/app.jar').eachByte { b ->
        out.write(b)
    }
```

But the same scripts works perfectly when I download something from Maven central repository.

What could be the issue? Is there any SSL certificate issue with my nexus that is causing the download to be broken? Because, when I use `curl` and download it using `-k` flag it downloads the file perfectly because it makes the connection `insecure.`

I use `curl -k <NEXUS_REPO_PATH_TO_FILE> -O app.jar`

If there is any SSL issue then how can I suppress it using Groovy?

Comment: The code works...

Comment: see this example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674995/groovy-download-image-from-url

Comment: @aristotll the execution is successful but only downloads a 1KB JAR file but my JAR file in nexus is of 54KB.

Comment: @ANILMAHAPATRAOfficial The url is wrong, it is a html file, although it says it is a jar. You can browse the url in browser. Just open http://server.org.com/nexus/repo/1.11/app.jar

Comment: @aristotll that's just an example URL. I cannot provide my organization's actual nexus URL here. Test that script for this URL: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/beust/jcommander/1.48/jcommander-1.48.jar 

It is 53KB but it is not downloading the complete JAR either.

Comment: I changes the url, and in my computer the jar downloaded by Groovy has  the same size and hash as what I download using my browser.

Comment: Yeah it is working for Maven central repository but not for my nexus. I think we have some SSL certificate issue here, that's why it is not downloading the JAR completely. I have edited the question.